# Taking videos with opencv after some intervals

Tags: python, opencv, datetime, video

I am beginner in python and also in opencv. I want to take video of some interval with opencv videocapture function  let say 10 seconds and then system should go to sleep mode for some time let say for 6 seconds .then it takes video of 10 second .Both video should be saved in separate file.my problem is that when i call first function it save the first video but on call of  video2 function it doesn't save the video.sorry for bad arrangement of code . i am new user to so.

```
import cv2
import time
def delay(delay_time):
     timeout = delay_time   # [seconds]

     timeout_start = time.time()

     print(time.strftime("%c"))
    while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
          test = 0
          if test == 3:

             break
          test -= 1
     print(time.strftime("%c"))

def video1():



   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


   if (cap.isOpened() == False):
   print("Unable to read camera feed")

    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

    out = cv2.VideoWriter('Data/output1.avi', 
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))

   while time.time() < time_start + closing_time:
         ret, frame = cap.read()

         if ret == True:
        out.write(frame)

           cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

            else:
                break

   cap.release()
   out.release()

def video2():


   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

   if (cap.isOpened() == False):
   print("Unable to read camera feed")

    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

    out = cv2.VideoWriter('Data/output2.avi', 
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))

   while time.time() < time_start + closing_time:
         ret, frame = cap.read()

         if ret == True:

            out.write(frame)

           cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

            else:
                break

   cap.release()
   out.release()

   cv2.destroyAllWindows()


   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   print(time.strftime("%c"))
   video1()
   delay(6)
   print(time.strftime("%c"))
   video2()
```

Comment: Without much analysis: you got a constant output file. So yeah, of course you won't see multiple output files. You need to use different filenames in your loop (and probably refactor the place of creating the file-handler).

Comment: i have two function for saving 2 videos.first video opens normally but second file appears in folder First video opens normally but On opening says  can't demultiplex stream

Comment: Please modify the code to remove all comments and then we can see if there is any difference in saving the first video file and second video file. Also do both functions video1, video2 perform the same action of saving the video?

Comment: i removed all of the comments.

Comment: code saves two videos but whenever i tried to play the video with opencv video capture function opencv generates error OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)

Comment: whenever i tried to open that video file simply by clicking it gives Could not demultiplex stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has so many indentation problems that I can't even point to 1 location and say this is a problem. So I rearranged your code here. Also you didn't even define `time_start` or `closing_time` in your code. But I'm assuming your real code has them and the problem is just the second video not outputting right. Well that is because you have to define `time_start` in the beginning of `video1` and `video2`. If you don't re-define `time_start`, by the time you get to `video2` this `while time.time() < time_start + closing_time:` has already been exhausted and will be False. So no real video is being written to file.

```
import cv2
import time
def delay(delay_time):
    timeout = delay_time   # [seconds]
    timeout_start = time.time()
    print(time.strftime("%c"))
    while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
        test = 0
        if test == 3:
            break
            test -= 1
    print(time.strftime("%c"))

def video1():
    time_start = time.time()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
        print("Unable to read camera feed")
    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
    print(frame_width,frame_height)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi', 
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))

    while time.time() < time_start + closing_time:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            out.write(frame)
            #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    out.release()

def video2():
    time_start = time.time()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
        print("Unable to read camera feed")
    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
    print(frame_width,frame_height)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output2.avi', 
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))
    while time.time() < time_start + closing_time:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            out.write(frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    out.release()

print(time.strftime("%c"))
closing_time = 10
video1()
delay(6)
print(time.strftime("%c"))
video2()
# this loop is here because sometimes cv2 has problems destroying windows
# if you call it once. so to be safe I call it 10 times
for _ in range(10):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick it does what you asked in the question, the code is below:
`

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out=cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 48))
start_time=time.time()
while True:
    ret, frame=cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if time.time()-start_time>=10:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
time.sleep(6)
cap2=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc2=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out2=cv2.VideoWriter('output2.avi', fourcc2, 20.0, (640, 48))
start_time2=time.time()
while True:
    ret, frame=cap2.read()
    out2.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if time.time()-start_time2>=10:
        break
cap2.release()
out.release()
```

`

Comment: code saves two videos but whenever i tried to play the video  with opencv video capture function                                                                                                        
                             opencv generates error OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)

Comment: whenever i tried to open that video file simply by clicking it gives Could not demultiplex stream.